# Integrate ROS Groovy and QtCreator

Tags: ros, ros-groovy, qtcreator, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have successfully integrated the code ROS with QT libraries. To do
this I created the project with catkin_create_pkg and then I added all
the necessary (cpp file, ui, wrappers, etc.) in the file CMakeList.txt.

I am then able to successfully compile my project through catkin.
My question now is this: how do I continue
my work through the environment QtCreator? I know very well that the
QtCreator is capable of interpreted file from CMake, but not
by catkin.

My system is Ubuntu 12.04 and ROS Groovy Galapagos.

Thanks to all.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62572/integrate-ros-groovy-and-qtcreator./) by [Ziko](https://answers.ros.org/users/4701/ziko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2013-05-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to use QtCreator by running through the catkin
following steps:

1. Since QtCreator needs its own working directory that I put in
   a place where you do not bother.
2. In the "Build Settings"

2.1. I set the following custom build settings "build steps"

-command: catkin_make

-Working directory: /home/myuser/catkin_ws

-Command arguments: none

2.2. I set the following custom clean settings "clean steps"

-command: catkin_make clean

-Working directory: /home/myuser/catkin_ws

-Command arguments: none

3. In the "Run Settings" menu I have replaced the "Run" default configuration with my custom:

-Run configuration: MyCustomRunConfiguration

-Executable: my_executable

-Arguments: none

-Working diretcory: /home/myuser/catkin_ws/devel/lib/my_executable

I know that is not a permanent solution but only a trick,
also the folder created by QtCreator is never used. to
now is the best I could do.

---

Originally posted by [Ziko](https://answers.ros.org/users/4701/ziko/) with karma: 46 on 2013-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think that you have to do anything special to get QtCreator to build catkin packages. At least, I don't do anything (besides sourcing the ROS setup files in my .bashrc file). All you need to do is open the CMakeLists.txt file as a project and mine works. I also start QtCreator from a terminal, because it does not work when launched from the Ubuntu drop-down menu. (I assume because of sourcing the setup files, but I'm not 100% sure about this.)

---

Originally posted by [stantol](https://answers.ros.org/users/2884/stantol/) with karma: 146 on 2013-05-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ziko](https://answers.ros.org/users/4701/ziko/) on 2013-05-13**:
Yes, source the setup file before running qtcreator is necessary.

**Comment by [trianta2](https://answers.ros.org/users/8336/trianta2/) on 2014-01-14**:
You do not have to launch qtcreator from terminal. Edit your qtcreator.desktop file and replaced the Exec line with: "Exec=bash -i -c qtcreator %F" ... now you can use the icon from the launch bar.